# How to groupby name and concat all reviews in python dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, concatenation, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.read_csv('movie_lens')
df1 = df.groupby([['name of movie','reviews']])

##Groupby name of the movie and put all reviews for that movie into one row..#
#name of movie.............reviews#
#titanic...................good#
#titanic...................bad#
#titanic....................great#
#superbad..................funny#
#superbad..................ok#
#superbad..................hilarious#

#How to group movies into one row and concatenate all review it a CSV that's now a dataframe.example#  
#titanic....................good.bad.great#
#superbad....................funny.ok.hilarious#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply grouped by too many things.
You want:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['name of movie'])['reviews'].apply(list)
```

Or, slightly simpler:

```
df1 = df.groupby('name of movie').reviews.apply(list)
```

Once you have a `list` of reviews,
feel free to `join()` them using `' '` or similar.